# Jersey client REST API generates http 403 error

Tags: java, jersey-client

Jersey client REST-API on mine java project generate HTTP 403 error. Though this project running fine for calling other Restful API except fake online based REST API `JSONPlaceholder`. Please find mine following code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource webResource =   client.resource("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
    ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
            .get(ClientResponse.class);
    if(response.getStatus() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed http error code :" + response.getStatus());
    }
    String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
    System.out.println(output);
```

#### Error:

[image: Click this link to see error !]

Comment: Does the API require any credentials?

Comment: @peeskillet no man, its fetching fine for all browsers but not working when i called it from mine java code snippet.

Comment: Ureka!! its working! i just set header on WebResource instance with "user-agent" argument { webResource.accept("application/json")
    .header("user-agent", "") }.  Thats it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in comment, setting key `("user-agent")` and value `("")` in header on webResource instance leads the solution. Hope Following code snippet give you better idea.

```
Client client = Client.create();
WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
ClientResponse response = webResource.accept("application/json")
            .header("user-agent", "")
            .get(ClientResponse.class);
if(response.getStatus() != 200) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed http error code :" + response.getStatus());
}
String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
System.out.println(output);
```

Thank you all for your great feedback.

Answer (score 2):

As I read the question yesterday I instinctively thought of the user-agent header. Your comment proves it. Just to give a more readable answer, I'll provide the following working code regarding to your example (nevertheless I bet providing no UA is not the best way ;) ).

```
Client c = Client.create();
WebResource wr = c.resource("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts");
ClientResponse resp = wr.accept("application/json").header("user-agent", "").get(ClientResponse.class);
if (resp.getStatus() != 200) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed http error code :" + resp.getStatus());
}
String output = resp.getEntity(String.class);
System.out.println(output);
```